# How to make a Gtk+ widget inside a GtkScrolledWindow to expand when packed into a GtkPane?

Tags: c, gtk, gtktreeview, gtkscrolledwindow

I have a program which shows two [`GtkTreeView`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkTreeView.html)s packed inside a [`GtkPaned`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkPaned.html) ([sscce](http://sscce.org/): [here](http://pastebin.com/jzTT0zSA)):

```
gtk_paned_add1(GTK_PANED(paned), tree_view1);
gtk_paned_add2(GTK_PANED(paned), tree_view2);
```

The result is the following:

[image: Window presenting the two tree views]

However, the tables can become bigger, so I added then to [`GtkScrolledWindow`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkScrolledWindow.html)s (sscce: [here](http://pastebin.com/uW0EAvTS)):

```
GtkWidget *scrolled_window1 = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL),
          *scrolled_window2 = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolled_window1), tree_view1);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolled_window2), tree_view2);
gtk_paned_add1(GTK_PANED(paned), scrolled_window1);
gtk_paned_add2(GTK_PANED(paned), scrolled_window2);
```

However, now the window collapses itself to the point it is almost a thin trance, as in the screenshot below:

[image: Insanely small window]

If I maximize the window, the first column does not appear (although I can manually expand it):

[image: The first table does not appear]

So, what is the best method of getting the appearance of the first screenshot wen using `GtkScrolledWindows` in this scenario? Also, could I define the size of the pane columns in relation to one another (for example, 30% for the first one, 70% for the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I adopted was to actually set the size of the scrolled windows ([sscce](http://pastebin.com/8039K2sP)):

```
gtk_widget_set_size_request(scrolled_window1, 200, 600);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(scrolled_window2, 600, 600);
```

The result was, as one would expect, a window with 800x600:

[image: A window with good dimentions]

I am not satisfied: this approach relies on arbitrary sizes and it seems too "manual". Nonetheless, I want to use my software so I will adopt it for now.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this pattern (I'd be happy if someone posted a better answer):

```
GtkWidget* treeView_, pane1_;
// [Removed code to create and show the widget heirarchy.]
GtkRequisition sizeReq;
gtk_widget_size_request(treeView_, &sizeReq);  // get tree's preferred size
gtk_paned_set_position(GTK_PANED(pane1_), sizeReq.width);
```

This gets pretty close, but you'll probably have a horizontal scrollbar with a few hidden pixels.  Since our application remembers the user's adjustments to the pane positions, it only needs to look "good enough" on initial layout.

Also, there are requirements for gtk_widget_size_request() returning something meaningful.  In my case, I've invoked a gtk_widget_show_all() on the hierarchy before retrieving the size request.

Comment: This did not worked, either: I ran [a modified version of my examples](http://pastebin.com/jW652h0H) and the window was still collapsed.

Comment: In your example, you didn't set the overall size of the window and the left pane gets sets to a small size because the strings are short and the scroll policy isn't set to automatic.  The scrollbar is a large percentage of the width needed to show the strings "left 1" and "left 2".  Try [this modified version of your paste](http://pastebin.com/6sFitdjc).

Comment: Fair enough; with your update, it really works. On the other hand, when I resize the window to a very small size and then resize it to a bigger size, the width of the first pane stays small. For this reason, I still use my own, half-baked solution but your solution works, too, specially if one is happy to ignore such detail.